# MySQL event not triggering

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-event

I've created the following event, but for some reason it's not getting triggered:

```
CREATE EVENT Del_logs
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
DO
    TRUNCATE TABLE security.errors;
```

Is there any log I could check to see what went wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your server is on the same timezone as you are? Try setting the start date to 2 days ago to see.

Comment: The error log file is generally `/var/log/mysqld.log` but if you're on a hosted system you might not have access to it. Not all hosted systems have the event scheduler enabled. You should check with your ISP

Comment: The server is dedicated, I have full root access to it and it is on the same timezone. Could it be some MariaDB incompatibility with events?
The error log seems to be empty

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the event scheduler is OFF.

- use [`SHOW PROCESSLIST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-processlist.html) to check if the event scheduler is enabled. If it's ON you should see a process "`Daemon`" by user "`event_scheduler`".
- use

  ```
  SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
  ```

  to enable the scheduler if it's currently not enabled.
- More on configuring event scheduler read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html)